# Can't navigate with flutter WebViewWidget

Tags: android, ios, flutter, webview, stripe-payments

I'm using the package (webview_flutter)[https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter], to show a webview. I want to trigger a certain function when the user gets directed to a specific url, but I always get this error:

```
W/cr_AwContentsClient( 4446): Denied starting an intent without a user gesture, URI https://checkout.stripe.dev/success
```

This is my controller initialization code:

```
webController = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            log("onProgress $progress");
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            log("onPageStarted $url");
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            log("onPageFinished $url");
          },
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
            log("onWebResourceError $error");
          },
          onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
            inspect(request);
            if (request.url.startsWith(successUrl)) {
              status.value = CheckoutStatus.successful;
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            } else if (request.url.startsWith(canceledUrl)) {
              status.value = CheckoutStatus.canceled;
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(url));

    if (webController.platform is AndroidWebViewController) {
      AndroidWebViewController.enableDebugging(true);
      (webController.platform as AndroidWebViewController)
          .setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
```

I don't care about the redirect itself to work, I just want to read the url (Which clearly works somehow because the errormessage shows the correct url that I want to read).

Comment: Did you set the permissions for Android to use the Internet?

Comment: The initial url loads just fine, only the redirect doesn't work